# Puppeteer element can't be reached with selector

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, puppeteer, screen-scraping

I want to get the src of multiple images but their selectors don't seem to work, like the elements are fake and aren't actually in the page.

https://imgflip.com/memegenerator/Drake-Hotline-Bling

This is one of the pages, every page has one of my desired elements (the main image), each with the same selector.

I have tried multiple selectors like:

`'#mm-preview-outer > div.mm-preview > img'`and `'img[alt="meme generator image preview"]'`but they don't work.

I tested my code by scraping other elements and everything works but when I change the selector in the `.$eval()` to my desired element it doesn't work (no errors).

This is my code working correctly with a different selector:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async()=>{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless:false,
        defaultViewport:false,
        userDataDir:'./tmp'
    });


    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const page2 = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://imgflip.com/memetemplates');

    const boxes = await page.$$('.mt-boxes > .mt-box');
    for(const box of boxes){
        try {
            const title = await page.evaluate((el) => el.querySelector('h3 > a').textContent, box);
            const pageurl = await page.evaluate((el) => el.querySelector('a.mt-caption').getAttribute('href'), box);

            await page2.goto(`https://imgflip.com${pageurl}`);
            const imageurl = await page.$eval('img[alt="Imgflip Logo"]', el => el.src);
            console.log('The source of',title,'is')
            console.log(imageurl);
        } catch(error){}
    }
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Technically all I need to do is to change `'img[alt="Imgflip Logo"]'` to `'img[alt="meme generator image preview"]'` but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `img[alt="meme generator image preview"]` you can use

- `'img.mm-img'` or `'img[class^=mm-img]'` selectors *(note : `^` means begins with)*
- and you need to replace `el.src` with `el.getAttribute('src')`

so change

```js
const imageurl = await page.$eval('img[alt="Imgflip Logo"]', el => el.src);
```

to

```js
 const imageurl = await page2.$eval('img[class^=mm-img]', el => el.getAttribute('src'));
```

in your code.

you can also re-write some of the other parts like below, even though they are not necessary for what you want.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async()=>{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless:false,
        defaultViewport:false,
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();    
    await page.goto('https://imgflip.com/memetemplates', {waitUntil: "load", timeout: 15000 });
    await page.waitForSelector('#page');
    const boxes = await page.$$('.mt-box');

    let allMemes = [];
    for(let box of boxes){
        try {
            let title = await box.$eval('h3 > a', el => el.textContent);
            let link = await box.$eval('a.mt-caption', el => el.getAttribute('href'));

            const page2 = await browser.newPage();      
            await page2.goto(`https://imgflip.com${link}`, {waitUntil: "load", timeout: 15000 });
            await page2.waitForSelector('body');

            const imageurl = await page2.$eval('img[class^=mm-img]', el => el.getAttribute('src'));

            console.log("The source of", title, "is");
            console.log(imageurl);

            await page2.close();

        } catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    await browser.close();

})();
```

If you need to get the already existing memes then you can do it this way..

Code :

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async()=>{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless:false,
        defaultViewport:false,
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();    
    await page.goto('https://imgflip.com/memetemplates', {waitUntil: "load", timeout: 15000 });
    await page.waitForSelector('#page');
    const boxes = await page.$$('.mt-box');

    let allMemes = [];
    for(let box of boxes){
        try {
            let data = await box.$eval('.mt-title > a', el => {return { link : el.getAttribute('href'), text : el.textContent}});
            const page2 = await browser.newPage();      
            await page2.goto(`https://imgflip.com${data.link}`, {waitUntil: "load", timeout: 15000 });
            await page2.waitForSelector('body');
            // some pages have empty or ads in .base-unit without any h2, so the :has(h2) selector checks if the div has a h2 or not.
            let memes = await page2.$$(".base-unit:has(h2)");
            let relative = [];
            for (let m of memes) { // get all relative memes on the page
                let title = await m.$eval('h2 > a', el => {return { link: el.getAttribute("href"), text: el.textContent };});
                // some pages have the image in an a tag, others have it in a div tag, so if div get data-src if a tag get src.
                let image = (!! await m.$('div.base-img')) ? await m.$eval('.base-img', el => el.getAttribute("data-src")) : await m.$eval('.base-img', el => el.getAttribute("src"));                
                relative.push({ link: title.link, text : title.text, image: image});
            }
            await page2.close();

            allMemes.push({
                link : data.link,
                text : data.text,
                relative : relative
            });

        } catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    await browser.close();

    console.dir(allMemes, { depth: null }); // same as log, but show all objects

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use `querySelect` on `alt` or `title` attributes when you can use classes or ids.

This selector works in the console maybe it'll help:

```
document.querySelector('.mm-preview img').src
```